# C# - Wait for Multiple File Downloads to Complete

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have an app written in C#. In this app, I need to download multiple files. Once all of the files are downloaded, I need to do something else. In an effort to download the files at the same time, I've written the following:

```
private void DownloadFiles(string[] targets)
{
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  foreach (var target in targets)
  {
    var task = DownloadFile(target);
    tasks.Add(task);
  }

  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

private async Task DownloadFile(string target)
{
  using (var wc = new WebClient())
  {
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) => {
      Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage + "% downloaded.");
    }

    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) => {
      Console.WriteLine(target + " was downloaded.");

      // TODO: Signal this "Task" is done
    }

    await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(target, localPath);
  }
}
```

Maybe I'm confused. In my opinion, I think I need to do something in `DownloadFileCompleted`. Or, maybe the `await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync` line is sufficient.

How do I download multiple files at the same time, but wait until they're all download before continuing?

Comment: and what is wrong with your code?

Comment: @demo I think his problem is that he effectively doesn't download in parallel (which he obviously wants to do) because he awaits `DownloadFileTaskAsync` in the `DownloadFile` method

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
private void DownloadFiles(string[] targets)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        foreach (var target in targets)
        {
            var task = DownloadFile(wc, target);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}


private Task DownloadFile(WebClient wc, string target)
{            
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) =>
    {
         Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage + "% downloaded.");
    };

    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) =>
    {
         Console.WriteLine(target + " was downloaded.");
         // TODO: Signal this "Task" is done
    };

    return wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(target, localPath);
 }
```

I moved the WebClient to the calling method because you will have to keep it open until all downloads finished (which you don't know when they will within your `DownloadFile` method).

Additionally I removed the `async` from your method declaration because you don't have to wait for something within the method.